# Notebook GSM modem responding to incoming calls on mobile phone

Tags: networking, modem

I few weeks ago, i bought a used Sierra EM7455 gsm modem for my Thinkad l470, which seems to be working perfectly with the inserted second multi-sim from my operator. After some days i noticed, that every incoming call is going to be declined on my iphone when the thinkpad is turned on at the same time. The strange thing here is, that it's not enough to cancel the internet connection, to get calls work. I have to disable the modem manually with `nmcli r wwan off`, to get the calls delivered to my mobile phone.

**Question**

Does any of you know, how this can be turned off, so my notebook just ignores the incoming calls instead of declining them?

**What did i already tried?**

At first, i installed a firmware update on the module to the newest version. This doesn't changed anything.

I read somewhere, that there is an option to send at commands to the module, providing some extra options, but that didn't worked well for me. At first look, the module doesn't seem to had a open serial port (something like a `/dev/ttyS*` or `/dev/ttyUSB*` file) to connect to. Right after the firmware update, the `dmesg | grep tty` gave me this:

```
[    0.123755] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[    7.220331] usb 1-9: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    7.226860] usb 1-9: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[    7.233900] usb 1-9: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB2
```

The only port that is accessible for a tool like `picocom`, is `/dev/ttyUSB1`, but whenever i try to connect, i can't type anything into the at console. This behavior is independently of the tool, i tried `putty` (in serial mode), `minicom` and `cu`. Whenever the at console opens, i can't type anything into it. Maybe i am doing something wrong here handling these at commands?

**Some data about my computer**

My computer runs with Ubuntu 20.04. The output of `uname -r` is `5.4.0-39-generic`.

The output from `mmcli -m 2` is:

```
  --------------------------------
  General  |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/2
           |            device id: 9214d5288d00d12e55a687c1cdbfa0fb19f4d867
  --------------------------------
  Hardware |         manufacturer: Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
           |                model: Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A
           |    firmware revision: SWI9X30C_02.33.03.00
           |       carrier config: default
           |         h/w revision: EM7455
           |            supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |              current: gsm-umts, lte
           |         equipment id: 015105000969220
  --------------------------------
  System   |               device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9
           |              drivers: cdc_mbim, qcserial
           |               plugin: Sierra
           |         primary port: cdc-wdm0
           |                ports: cdc-wdm0 (mbim), ttyUSB0 (qcdm), ttyUSB2 (at), wwan0 (net)
  --------------------------------
  Status   |       unlock retries: sim-pin2 (3)
           |                state: connected
           |          power state: on
           |          access tech: lte
           |       signal quality: 25% (cached)
  --------------------------------
  Modes    |            supported: allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |              current: allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
  --------------------------------
  Bands    |            supported: utran-1, utran-3, utran-4, utran-5, utran-8, utran-2, 
           |                       eutran-1, eutran-2, eutran-3, eutran-4, eutran-5, eutran-7, eutran-8, 
           |                       eutran-12, eutran-13, eutran-20, eutran-25, eutran-26, eutran-41
           |              current: utran-1, utran-3, utran-4, utran-5, utran-8, utran-2, 
           |                       eutran-1, eutran-2, eutran-3, eutran-4, eutran-5, eutran-7, eutran-8, 
           |                       eutran-12, eutran-13, eutran-20, eutran-25, eutran-26, eutran-41
  --------------------------------
  IP       |            supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  --------------------------------
  3GPP     |                 imei: 015105000969220
           |        enabled locks: fixed-dialing
           |          operator id: 26203
           |        operator name: Simply
           |         registration: home
  --------------------------------
  3GPP EPS | ue mode of operation: csps-2
  --------------------------------
  SIM      |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/2
  --------------------------------
```

I'm a completely new into this, so i'm sorry if am overlooked something trivial.

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

After some more research it looks like, that the gsm modem is responding to the phone call with a "yes, i'll take the call", without notifying me. This response seams to reach the provider, which sends a "caller busy" signal to my phone right after the first ring. Maybe there is a modem-manager configuration anywhere, which says, that the modem just has to ignore the incoming signal?